# Snowflake SQL Regex

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to identify a value that is nested in a string using Snowflakes regexp_substr()

The value that I want to access is in quotes:

```
...
Type:
value: "CategoryA"
...
```

Edit: This text is nested in a much larger portion of text.

I want to extract CategoryA for all columns using regexp_substr. But I am unsure how. 
I have tried:

```
regexp_substr(col, 'Type\\W+(\\w+)\\W+\\w.+')
```

and while that gives the portion of the string, I just want what is in quotes and can't figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regexp_replace() instead:

```
regexp_replace(col, '(^[^"]*")|("[^"]*$)", '')
```

The regexp matches on both following conditions, and replaces matching parts with the empty string:

- `^[^"]*"`: everything from the beginning of the string to the first double quote
- `("[^"]*$)"`: everything from the last double quote to the end of the string

Comment: I failed to mention that there is text before and after that small portion of text.

Comment: @making: as long as there is just one string surrounded with double quotes, this should work. Please give it a try against your real data.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This seems to work if I do: 
regexp_replace(regexp_substr(col, 'Type\\W+(\\w+)\\W+\\w.+'), '(^[^"]*")|("[^"]*$)", '')

There are multiple stings that are surrounded by double-quotes.